# Possibility of visa for "household members" for Canada and UK for 1 year-similar to U.S.A?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, canada, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen. If I stay in U.S.A for 1 year then I can bring my parents **for 1 year** to U.S.A using the "B2 visa for household members". See for example [here](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040202.html#M402_2_4_B_5)
or the last answer of [this stack exchange question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64096/can-i-be-admitted-for-more-than-six-months-on-a-b-2-visa).

My question is the following:

Does such kind of permit/visa exists for Canada and UK? That is, if I go to Canada or UK, can I get a suitable visa to bring my parents to Canada or UK for **1 year**. I searched over the internet and I came to know that for 6 months this *is possible* using a tourist or "visitor" visa. My intention is to bring my parents for 1 year. For U.S.A, this is also possible for 1 year as I explained above. I want to know whether similar thing is possible for Canada and UK. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is very broad and should be broken down into at least two questions - one for Canada one for UK, with what sort of visa you would be on

Comment: I prefer to keep one question instead of two different questions with essentially the same content.

Answer (score 1):

For Canada, any length of stay is theoretically possible on a visitor visa, but for visitors from developing countries the authorities are very exacting in demanding proof that they won't work and will return when their approved stay expires. This is usually easiest if the visitor has a large bank account and property in the home country.